# Remove table row if it is equivalent to a value

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to display a list of users on a table and remove the row which contains the current user. I have looked at [this](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/32794-skip-remove-row-on-load-of-tableview.html) an [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/04/19/static-uitableview-programmatically-remove-cell/) post but it didn't work for me. Each of my user has their own unique id which I can check if it exists. However I am not sure about the function needed to remove a specific row.

I have attempted this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let users = UserManager.shared.users[indexPath.row]

    if(users.key == "") {
    // Skip the specific user

    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: are you trying to remove an existing row, or you are just trying to solve only some of the users from the very beginning? removing cell means that you have a table with all the users, and then you remove a cell from it.. from the fact that you are showing `cellForRowAt` implementation it seems more that you are trying to just filter out some users

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I only want some of the users from the very beginning. Sp should this take place at the numberOfRowsInSection?

Answer (score 1):

Make the backing array for the table match what you want to display.  In other words, let `UserManager` do the managing.

`UserManager` should provide you a user from an array that already excludes the one you wish to avoid showing.

Answer (score 1):

Add a filtered user property to your `UserManager` that would include only those users, that you want to show. You can for example use the following computed property:

```
extension UserManager {
    var filteredUsers: [User] {
        self.users.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            // if users.key != "key" is true, the user will be included
            return users.key != "key"
        })
    }
}
```

Then instead of using `UserManager.shared.users` use `UserManager.shared.filteredUsers` in `numberOfRows` and in `cellForRowAt`.

Of course, if users don't change, it would be better to precompute the filtered users instead of computing it every time the `UserManager.shared.filteredUsers` is accessed. But you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure, where your users you want to display are. If they are in an array just make a new array with the row to remove excluded or just remove them from the existing one with removeAtIndexPath whatever.

After that just reload the tableView if necessary.

Just don't forget that you also need to update numberOfRows with

return filteredArray.count

> So in your if statement just create the new filteredArray else use the existing UserManager.shared.users

```
 if(users.key == "") {

     yourArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
     tableView.reloadData()

}
```

or

```
if(users.key == "") {

     let newFilteredArray: Array = oldArray  //maybe UserManager.shared.users

     newFilteredArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
     tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: with the array.remove(at: indexPath.row). Maybe your array is defined with let, then you can't. You need to change it than to var or create a new one or how do you mean specific data?

Comment: Oh wow, your method works very well. But is this safe and good practice? The other questions also demonstrate how to achieve this by filtering the data in the `UserManager` class and then calling it after I fetch the data is fetched do an if statement at the `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: It doesn't really matter, both works but I guess this iOS just simpler

Comment: You don't need to do an if statement in `numberOfRowsInSection` because you already filtered the Array. So just put `return newArray.count` or `return filteredArray.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: No, I meant if I was to go and do the filter at the numberOfRowsInSection instead at the cellForRowAt like you have recommended. `UserManager` is responsible for "managing" user data after all

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can generate this current user row by Hiding .

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
   let users = UserManager.shared.users[indexPath.row]

   if(users.key == "") {
   return 0
  }

  return someFloatVlaue;//Choose your custom row height
}
```